# IOTOP complains: CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT not enabled in kernel

Tags: systemd-boot, iotop

Looking about, I see that the standard fix is to add this to the kernel boot parameters.

Using systemd-boot, my arch.conf looks like this :

```
 title   Arch Linux
 linux   /vmlinuz-linux
 initrd  /intel-ucode.img
 initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
 options root=PARTUUID="98b3b4f7-e7f9-6f49-be81-a2ee709c7a3e" rw
```

How do I add CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT to the `options` entry?

Another line?

Or by using some delimeter, add it to the existing line?

What value should I be setting it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kernel *build* option, so you cannot "add" it at runtime.

Either build your own kernel, or ask your maintainer to build the kernel with this option which they may or may not do because some kernel options depend on others and those dependencies might be very undesirable, e.g. they could slow down the kernel considerably.

Comment: `CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT` is typically already enabled in kernel but since patch https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e4042ad492357fa995921376462b04a025dd53b6 the runtime toggle defaults to off. You either have to add kernel flag `delayacct` or write `1` to `/proc/sys/kernel/task_delayacct` while the system is running.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a simple fix for the iotop error you have encountered but getting there from here is roundabout.

[TL;DR:  If using systemd-boot, simply add a new line reading `options delayacct` to the end of your sd-boot entry configuration file.  GRUB has corresponding syntax.  Alternative, non-boot-manager config options also exist that may be preferable.]

@Artem is correct that `CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT` is a kernel configuration, or build, option.  He also is correct that, as such, it bears on how the kernel is compiled and can't be added at runtime, *i.e.*, at boot.

Still, iotop often throws this error even when `CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT` is set to "y" because many distributions compile the kernel with this option but disable it by default.

This means that recompiling the kernel probably is a waste of time notwithstanding the literal meaning of the iotop error message.  To confirm, just check the kernel config file.  This file (config-*kernel-version*) typically is in the same directory as the kernel (vmlinuz-*kernel-version*) and initrd (initrd.img-*kernel-version*) files, *e.g.*, `/boot` or perhaps `/efi` depending on where the EFI system partition is mounted.  So, do, *e.g.*:

```
grep TASK_DELAY_ACCT /boot/config*
```

This may return something like:

```
/boot/config-5.15.0-41-generic:CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT=y
/boot/config-5.15.0-43-generic:CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT=y
```

The `=y` tells us that the kernel was compiled with this option.  This doesn't make the iotop error message any less enigmatic but it does confirm that the kernel is OK.  If so, then check the corresponding kernel parameter, `kernel.task_delayacct`, because enabling it should fix the iotop error.  To check the parameter, do:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/task_delayacct
```

If this returns 0, it's disabled; 1, enabled.  To enable the parameter, do one of:

- For the current session:

  `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/task_delayacct`

  This should have immediate effect without reboot.
- More persistently, add the following on a new line in either `/etc/sysctl.conf` or a .conf drop-in file in `/etc/sysctl.d`:

  `kernel.task_delayacct=1`

  or just do:

  `# echo "kernel.task_delayacct=1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/20-kernel-task-delayacct.conf`

  Reboot to take effect.
- Add `delayacct` to the kernel command line, depending on boot manager.  This is the approach you were pursuing in asking about systemd-boot.

  ***For GRUB2***, add or edit the following line in `/etc/default/grub` to read:
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="delayacct"`

  then save and close the file and do:

  `# update-grub`

  Reboot to take effect.

  ***For systemd-boot***, edit your *entry*.conf file and simply add a new line reading:

  `options delayacct`

  Systemd-boot [permits](https://systemd.io/BOOT_LOADER_SPECIFICATION) the `options` key to appear in a boot loader entry file more than once, so simply adding an additional line, instead of editing an existing `options` key, should be fine.

  Reboot to take effect.